# How do I actually print the numbers I'm storing in the variables X and Y? Assembly x86

Tags: assembly, printing, numbers, ascii, tasm

I need to read and print the numbers stored in two variables (I'm doing a menu program) but when I print them it prints the small letters from the ASCII table ( like a,b,c instead of 2,3,4). I know I'm supposed to substract 48 and multiply but I didn't find a great solution on how to implement that transformation in my program. I'm using Assembly x86, TASM.

This is the code from reading the inputs:

scriere:

```
mov dx, offset prompt1
   mov ah, 9
   int 21h

        input_x:

    mov bx, offset x ; point BX to the start of the array x
    mov cx, 10 ; set the counter to the number of elements in the array x

    input_loop1:
        mov ah, 01h ; function to read a single character
        int 21h ; call DOS function

        mov [bx], al ; store the character in the current array element
        inc bx ; move to the next array element

        loop input_loop1 ; repeat until counter reaches 0

    jmp input_y


        input_y:

mov dx, offset prompt2
mov ah, 9
int 21h

    mov bx, offset y ; point BX to the start of the array y
    mov cx, 10 ; set the counter to the number of elements in the array y

    input_loop2:
        mov ah, 01h ; function to read a single character
        int 21h ; call DOS function

        mov [bx], al ; store the character in the current array element
        inc bx ; move to the next array element

        loop input_loop2 ; repeat until counter reaches 0
    jmp bucla
```

and the problem I think comes from my printing code:

afisare:

```
 mov dx, offset prompt3
   mov ah, 9
   int 21h

  print_x:
    mov bx, offset x ; point BX to the start of the array x
    mov cx, 10 ; set the counter to the number of elements in the array x

    print_loop1:
        mov dl, [bx] ; move the value of the current array element to DL
        add dl, 48 ; convert the number to its ASCII equivalent
       
        mov ah, 02h ; function to print a single character
        int 21h ; call DOS function

        inc bx ; move to the next array element
        loop print_loop1 ; repeat until counter reaches 0

    jmp print_y


  print_y:

 mov dx, offset prompt4
   mov ah, 9
   int 21h

    mov bx, offset y ; point BX to the start of the array y
    mov cx, 10 ; set the counter to the number of elements in the array y

    print_loop2:
        mov dl, [bx] ; move the value of the current array element to DL
        add dl, 48 ; convert the number to its ASCII equivalent

        mov ah, 02h ; function to print a single character
        int 21h ; call DOS function

        inc bx ; move to the next array element
        loop print_loop2 ; repeat until counter reaches 0

jmp bucla ; return to main loop
```

Comment: adding/subtracting `0'` to convert between an integer and the ASCII code for the digit that represents it only works for numbers from 0..9.  See [Displaying numbers with DOS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45904075) for printing larger numbers.

Answer (score 0):

> How do I actually print the numbers I'm storing in the variables X and Y?

You have stored the ASCII representation of your numbers in the X and Y variables. Therefore printing the numbers does not require any conversion. Just remove the lines `add dl, 48` from the *afisare* code.

But if you did want to convert the inputted numbers from text to integer, then read about it in [Inputting multi-radix multi-digit signed numbers with DOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72407637/inputting-multi-radix-multi-digit-signed-numbers-with-dos).

For displaying such integers read [Displaying numbers with DOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45904075/displaying-numbers-with-dos).

Comment: When I remove the "add dl, 48" lines it doesn't print anything anymore.. I think I need to do the operation when I substract 48 and multiply it with another number to convert the number I write to the ASCII representation for 1, 2, 3 etc. but I don't know how to implement it because It doesn't work for both.

Comment: @purplemagictimes If **nothing** gets printed anymore then you are doing something else to the variables X and Y between *scriere* and *afisare*. What *you* call "the operation when I substract 48 and multiply it with another number to convert the number" is described in the first link I gave. Read it and **learn from it**. You are not supposed to find a ready-made solution, but you can steal the ideas that I provided through the linked posts. And if *your* implementation then has problems, return to this forum with your technical question...